# How to make Eclipse RCP 3.x EditorPart unclosable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

It seems like I couldn't find a way to remove the "close" icon next to each Editor to make it unclosable. I guess with RCP e4, its possible to make editor unclosable, but my application is 3.x, is there any way?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this. It may be possible to use a custom renderer for the part stack (this is e4 code but will work for 3.x parts as well provided you are using Eclipse 4).

Comment: im using eclipse 3.x, its not an easy way to migrate my existing part to e4 part unfortunately. is there anyway that i can override the close event? let's say, its clickable but do nothing

Comment: As I said you don't have to be using e4, just running Eclipse 4.

Comment: thanks @greg-449 i will give it a try

Comment: [Refer to Frank's solution from this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654473/remove-or-disable-the-x-close-button-shown-on-a-rap-rcp-editorpart) Perfectly work for my case.